# Background Image not Displaying Correctly in iOS

Tags: ios, css, ipad, background-image

I am using a tile-able background image on a website. The site views great in all desktop browsers but when I view the site on my iPad Mini (running iOS 6.1.3) the background image has streaks in it. You can see a pattern on most pages that is a line (the size of the background image) that looks fine, then another line again the same size of the background image, etc.

Here is a screenshot showing the issues:

[image: iPad Error Screenshot]

Here is the CSS required for the background:

```
#wrap {  
   margin:0 auto; 
   position:relative; 
   padding:0; 
   background: #B3B1B2 url(/images/bgs/parchment2.jpg); 
}
```

I tried clearing the cache of the iPad but that did not work. I am at a loss as why this is happening. How do I prevent and solve this issue?

***Update***

I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/mPuNj/1/) of the wrapper. It looked okay on the website. So I am left to assume it is somewhere in my code. However, this doesn't always happen immediately on the site. It may happen with the Fiddle but I have not seen it happen. If it is my site how do I track the code that is causing the issue?

***Update 2***

I changed the background image to the `html, body`tags and the issue still happens but isn't as bad and will clear it self. I am still left wondering how I prevent the issue all together.

***Update 3***

I tried @Riskbreaker's idea of switching to PNG. This did not work. I still see the lines. It also increased the background file substantially (from 30k to almost 200k). I also tried a completely different background image thinking it may be the image itself but I still saw the error. I switched back to jpg for file size considerations.

How do I solve this issue? Is it an iOS issue or something in my code?

The site in question is http://www.lfrieling.com/. I only see this on my iPad Mini running iOS 6.1.3 (latest as of this writing). I do not see this on my iPhone running same version of iOS. Also you see this on long pages more than other pages. See Professional > Resources.

Comment: Have you try changing the image to png? PNG is more web base friendly with most browsers....If you have Photoshop you can save for web and use progressive method

Comment: @Riskbreaker - I will give it a try. Never had jpgs give me an issue before.

Comment: I have an iPad(old school) and Nexus and all good...try adding specific to ipad2(mini...wish i had one to see what you see) from here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html
 and adding this to body: width: 100%; height: auto

Comment: @Riskbreaker - Unfortunately that did not work. I wonder if this issue is limited to the iPad Mini or possibly my iPad mini. It works fine on my iPhone 4 and it works fine on your devices. Thank You for looking.

Comment: I do not have the ability to test on the system you are having issues with. There are two things, however, I would try looking at. (1) do not have the img on both `html` and `body`, put it just on the `body`. (2) Try taking away the fading background img on the `.toc` and see if perhaps that is causing the display issue on the iPad Mini.

Comment: Yes try taking it off of the html and the body and just use it on the body.  Also use background: #B3B1B2 url(/images/bgs/parchment2.jpg) repeat center; See if that works. Otherwise and easy option would just to keep the background color.  Loading lots of images on background do tend to slow down sites a lot.

Comment: @Lynda: I'm still curious if any testing of removing the fading background on the `.toc` element (I realize that is not specifically the element you feel you have an issue with) affected the rendering of the background on the pages. The two main pages you have noted an issue with have that element in a significant size (i.e. it relates to your experiencing of it on "long pages" comment in your question).

Comment: @ScottS - I haven't tried to remove it but I feel that it isn't the issue because I saw this issue on pages that did not have the `.toc` class anywhere on the page.

Comment: @Lynda: true, but you use the same fading gradient on the `.left-navi` class as well (I think found on pages that don't have `.toc`), so it would show on other pages. The `.toc` is just longer on those pages, and seemed like a good test case to remove the background fade from to see if it was the source of the issue.

Comment: @ScottS - I tried removing these classes from the page and the error still happened. Only solution so far that seems to work is what Jason recommended. However, it may have caused another error, have to check this one out before I can be sure it is that code or my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried hardware acceleration? Add `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the same css as your adding the background. This is my guess because it appears to be a rendering issue and hardware acceleration fixes rendering issues when you use css transitions in Chrome.

```
#wrap {  
   margin:0 auto; 
   position:relative; 
   padding:0; 
   background: #B3B1B2 url(/images/bgs/parchment2.jpg);
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); 
}
```

Or maybe try retina display images for devices that support them using media queries?

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
  #wrap {  
   background: #B3B1B2 url(/images/bgs/parchment2_2x.jpg);
  }
}
```

[Media Query source *](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)

To solve the rendering issues you can try adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to other tags that are also wrapping content on the page. This may prevent loading/rendering issues.

Comment: The hardware acceleration idea seems to work. I need to do more testing before accepting. Also the iPad Mini is not a retina device but not a bad idea for devices that are retina enabled. Thanks

Comment: Using `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` does work, however, there is a problem. On the resource page (the longest page on the site) it stops loading about half-way down. If I remove `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` it loads without issue but the lines come back. Why does this stop the loading of the page?

Comment: This causes issues in Safari 5.1 (I am on Windows and do not have a higher version) and on the iPad Mini.

Comment: I believe I solved the rendering issues. I had to apply `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to other elements that wrap most of the content on the page. In my case `#main-content` and `#footer`. Seems to be working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lynda 
First of all this is a good looking website .
Second you should take in consideration these two advises :

1. The @media Rule

   and write a CSS file rules for each device ( here some a [List of medias](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) )
2. [Test your website on any screen size including desktops, tablets, televisions, and mobile phones.](https://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http://www.lfrieling.com&w=768&h=1024&a=22&s=1)

Thats all i think i have helped you .

Comment: Thank You for the compliment. However, your answer doesn't provide a solution to the problem and I am targeting devices through @media.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-webkit-background-size` to the body tag:

```
body {
    -webkit-background-size: 512px 512px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, This may help you. Add `overflow: hidden; height: 1%;` to your `#wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `background: #B3B1B2 url(/images/bgs/parchment2.jpg) repeat;`. Not sure it will solve the problem, and I don't own an iPad to test it but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this may help,

after adding `repeat` to `#wrap`,

and add `overflow:auto;` to `.height`

as the image size is 512x512 and .height is 2000.

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/mPuNj/2/)

I am not sure this will work but the problem is while rendering the inner image its not able to render the background properly,

FYI : -webkit-transform: uses gpu, so if the device is not gpu enabled then also you will face problem..

Hope this will do..