# -webkit-transform Prevents Page From Loading

Tags: ios, css, safari, webkit, webkit-transform

I have had an issue with the [Background Image not rendering correctly on the iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785085/background-image-not-displaying-correctly-in-ios). The answer provided which did solve the issue was to add `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the `id` that solved the issue but caused another one. On one page (which is a very long page) the content stops loading half-way through the page. If I remove `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` the issue stops (the background problem also reappears). Why does `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` prevent the page from loading?

CSS with webkit-transform:

```
#wrap {  
  margin:0 auto; 
  position:relative; 
  padding:0; 
  background: #B3B1B2 url(/images/bgs/parchment2.jpg);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); 
}
```

**Notes:**

- This happens on the iPad Mini running iOS 6.1.3
- This problem doesn't appear on the iPhone 4 (same version of iOS) or in Chrome.
- This does cause major issues in Safari 5.1 (I am running Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this rendering issue I had to trigger Hardware Acceleration on other elements on the page that were wrapping the content. In the cases of this site is was `#main-content` and `#footer`.

[This site](http://indiegamr.com/ios6-html-hardware-acceleration-changes-and-how-to-fix-them/) gave me the idea to try accelerating other items on the page and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
#wrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    background: #B3B1B2 url(/images/bgs/parchment2.jpg);
    -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0); 
}
```

or:

```
#wrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    background: #B3B1B2 url(/images/bgs/parchment2.jpg);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); 
}
```

Comment: `-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);` does prevent the weird loading issues. `-webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0);` stops long pages from loading completely. However `-webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);` doesn't seem to solve the issue that I was originally having from my [original question.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16785085/825757)