# Background images often corrupted (only observed in iOS devices)

Tags: ios, css, image, safari

I've developed a fairly graphic heavy website.

Mostly it is fully functional but a few users are observing a few corrupted background images when viewing from iPad or iPhone.

It doesn't seem to make a difference whether the image is a .jpg, .png or DataURI image.

Screenshots of the corrupted images can be seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCWLt.jpg

On an iPhone, refreshing the page doesn't make a difference. On and iPad apparently, it does. Most of the time and most of the images look absolutely fine.

The website is http://www.alternative-tune.co.uk/

The only other thing I wonder is could it be the color profile (simply because I don't have a clear understanding of them). Photoshop tells me it's: 
RGB: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
CMYK: US Web Coated (SWOP) v2

But surely this is ruled out by the fact that it works fine most of the time?

Does anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Many thanks,
Ben

Comment: Have you tried to re"Save for Web.." your images? Also.. Keep in mind that an image's optimal size for web (i'm talking about performances) is around 200KB. Your is 343KB.

Comment: Yes all images are made via "Save for Web" and the problem appears to be more common on a jpeg that has a size of 32KB...

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16928419/2600397).